# How to run Polly.NET asynchronously without blocking kafka message consumption

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, polly

I have a Kafka consumer that is calling an external API when it consumes a message. Polly.NET is used as a retrial mechanism in case the call is unsuccessful.

The problem with current solution is that the retrial mechanism is blocking the consumption of next message, so the next message has to wait retrial mechanism to finish.

Any idea how could i run the retrial mechanism asynchronously so i can continue with the next messages?

The below example demostrates the described problem:

```cs
using Confluent.Kafka;
using Polly;
using Polly.Extensions.Http;


var config = new ConsumerConfig
{
    BootstrapServers = "host1:9092,host2:9092",
    GroupId = "foo",
    AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest
};

using (var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(config).Build())
{
    // Awaiting retry policy here will block the consumption of next message
    var result = await GetRetryPolicy().ExecuteAsync(async () =>
    {
        // CALL AN API HERE...
        return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
    });
}


IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy()
{
    return HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError()
        .OrResult(msg => msg.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(5, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fully achieve asynchronous processing without blocking, you should indeed avoid awaiting the message consumption.

Here's the modified code:

```
using Confluent.Kafka;
using Polly;
using Polly.Extensions.Http;

var config = new ConsumerConfig
{
    BootstrapServers = "host1:9092,host2:9092",
    GroupId = "foo",
    AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest
};

using (var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(config).Build())
{
    var retryPolicy = GetRetryPolicy();

    while (true)
    {
        var result = consumer.Consume(); // This is a synchronous call

        // Start the asynchronous execution of the retry policy
        _ = retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
        {
            // CALL AN API HERE asynchronously, without awaiting the response...
            await YourApiCallAsync(); // Your API call should be asynchronous

            // Continue processing or log the result as needed
        });
    }
}

IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy()
{
    return HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError()
        .OrResult(msg => msg.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(5, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)));
}
```

In this code, the `result = consumer.Consume()` call is not awaited, allowing the Kafka consumer to continue processing messages asynchronously. The `retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync` call also starts the asynchronous execution of your API call without awaiting the response, ensuring that it doesn't block the message consumption loop.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One more question about async in .NET. How do we ensure that the asynchronous execution will not be "lost". Does not using the `await` keyword creates new thread? how can i ensure that the retrial will be run while the main program continue with message consumption. One last question. How do i get the Polly.NET Outcome when the retrial mechanism finishes. I want to log total failures. Could have that info in `.OnRetry` when building the policy?

Comment: Certainly, here's a shorter summary:
1) **Asynchronous Execution**: Asynchronous methods don't create new threads when not awaited; they run asynchronously within the same thread's context, avoiding main thread blocking.

2)**Ensuring Asynchronous Execution**: The code's retry policy runs asynchronously alongside the main message consumption loop, ensuring concurrent operation.
3) **Getting Polly.NET Outcome**: Use `.ExecuteAndCaptureAsync` to capture Polly.NET retry results, including success or failure, exception details, and retry attempts count.

Comment: This solution processes the messages in a fire and forget manner. Which means all failure is swallowed. Also most probably the message fetching is much faster than the message processing with the external service calls. That means your offsets are much advanced compared to the processed messages. In case of app crash and restart the kafka consumer will continue from the committed offset not from the last processed message. Depending on the use case it might be a huge problem.

Comment: Yes indeed this is a consideration, but in my case i don't want to do anything if a message totally fails. It's not that critical.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you shift from the synchronous execution world to the asynchronous one a bunch of new problem will arise.

Let's see couple of them. The very basic way to make the processing asynchronous is by separating the topic consumption from the message processing. Usually it is done in the way that there is a dedicated thread which fetches the messages from the Kafka topic and after the deserialization it dispatches the message processing to a worker thread. (Usually there is a worker thread pool which contains reusable threads.)

The very first problem what you will encounter here is the committing of the offsets. When should I do that? Before the dispatch or after a worker thread finishes the processing?

If we go with the before the dispatch approach (so, auto-committing offset) then the very next problem that we are facing is the error handling. What shall I do with those messages that failed during processing (including the retries)? Shall I put them back to the topic (like re-queuing it) for later consumption? Or shall I put it into a special topic called dead letter queue to handle those messages differently? Or simply just discard them?

If we go with the after the worker thread completes approach then we have yet another bunch of problems. The consumer application have to maintain where are we from processing perspective. What is the latest offset for each partition where we are sure that all messages before the offset are processed? When should we commit these offsets?

Another challenge is the message ordering. Imagine you have two messages (M1 and M2). Assume that M2's timestamp is greater than M1's timestamp. M2 message processing worked flawlessly and quickly. But M1's processing was a bit bumpy. The external service call had to be repeated multiple times due to transient network failure. In other words there is a point in time where M2 (which is a newer message) has been processed but M1 is not. Which offset should I commit in this case?

---

My point here is that creating a well-performing and correct asynchronous consumer is not as easy as having a synchronous one. So, I would double-check whether the promised scalability is worth the effort.